# $k^{-k}$ converges superlinearly but not quadratically.

Tags: convergence-divergence, optimization, numerical-optimization

A sequence $(x_k)$ converges to 0 superlinearly if $||x_{k+1}/x_k||\to0$ as $k\to\infty$.

A sequence $(x_k)$ converges to 0 quadratically if there exist $N,M>0$ such that $||x_{k+1}/x_k^2||<M$ for all $k>N$.

So far, to prove superlinearity, I have that $||\frac{k^k}{(k+1)^{(k+1)}}|| = ||(\frac{k}{k+1})^k\frac{1}{k+1}||\to 0$ as $k\to\infty$ since $\frac{k}{k+1}<1$ for all $k$. I feel like that argument is not sufficient but have not been able to come up with anything better. Edit: a very helpful comment has helped me tighten this argument.

I have also attempted to show that assuming there exists $N,M>0$ such that $||\frac{k^{2k}}{(k+1)^{(k+1)}}||<M$ for all $k>N$ leads to a contradiction. Lets pick $k=N+1$. Then we have
$||\frac{(N+1)^{2N+2}}{(N+2)^{(N+2)}}||<M$. So if we can show that there is no M such that this holds, we are done.

Any guidance would be appreciated!

Comment: Why would you think the argument is insufficient? It is absolutely enough to prove that the definition holds.

Comment: @Trebor My intuition was that since $\frac{k}{k+1}$ starts at 1/2 and approaches 1 as $k\to\infty$, it might be possible that taking the expression to the power $k$ might not decrease it fast enough to overcome the increase...

Comment: @OptiMath: If you want more rigor, show that $\left(\frac k{k+1}\right)^k\to 1/e$ and $\frac 1{k+1}\to 0$ as $k\to\infty$, both finite, so their product $\to (1/e)\times 0=0$

Comment: Your definitions for superlinear and quadratic convergence are equivalent. Are you missing a power or something in your definition? That might be why you are having trouble deriving a contradiction for quadratic convergence.

Comment: @Shiva There must be a typo in my lecture notes. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rate_of_convergence says that there should be a square on the denominator. I'll make the edit, thank you.